# Callout Error: Invalid session ID

Tags: callout

I am using schedulable class which will invoke apex call out. This is the salesforce web service from same org. I am getting the following error:

```
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session faultcode=sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID faultactor=
```

Can any one help me on this? I am using `UserInfo.getSessionId()` method to get session id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the session ID when running a batch:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm

Look up "getSessionId()" usage.